# Constraint to navigation item changes unexpected

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In my application I have a Login screen and after this comes a TabBarController with 3 Tabs. Here the screenshot of my Main.Storyboard:
[image: Main.storyboard]

The constraints for the EventTable and DrinkTable are the same. The first ViewController which shows after the Login screen is the EventViewController. In this view the table has the right margin to the navigation item.

Moving to the DrinkViewController the table has the wrong margin and it looks like this:[image: Drink View]
If I go the next ViewController by hitting the enter BarButton and going back to the DrinkViewController the margin of the table show correct:
[image: DrinkView after back]
What is the problem with my NavigationItem? Is there a difference betweent the TabBarController and NavigationController NavigationItem? Currently I am out of ideas how to get this working.
[image: The problematic view controller]
I guess the problem is not with the particular ViewController but with the TabBarController / NavigationController. If I swap the ViewControllers in the TabBarController just the one which is not shown in the beginning is broken as you can see in the 2nd picture.

Comment: do you have any kind of scrolling logic in `viewDidLoad`? it seems like the frame is correct, just that the tableView contentOffset is not 0 when the view is presented

Comment: No I have no scrolling logic in it. I will edit my question with the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the Extended Edges not set in the storyboard for all your view controllers.

[image]

Just deselect Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars there. This should do the trick

If you already have this set, maybe you could update the question with the actual view controller that looks wrong, I can't really see it in your storyboard screen shot.

Let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: Edited my question. This did not help.